# Mapping a list of ints into a list of MinMax ranges with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to convert a list of ints (`-100, -80, -60, -40, -20, 0`) into a list of min max range pairs `[-100, -80], [-80, -60], [-60,-40], [-40, -20], [-20, 0]`

I have a C style forloop that does this but it's very inelegant. It relies on the exception to stop processing. There should be a way to use a LINQ or an IEnumerable query for this, right? I've been trying to think of a query that could satisfy this but I'm coming up with blanks.

```
var signalStrengthBuckets = new List<IMinMaxRange<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < thresholdList.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        signalStrengthBuckets.Add(
        new MinMaxRange<int>(thresholdList[i], thresholdList[i + 1]));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "inelegant" or not ... I've seen LINQ do some HORRENDOUSLY inefficient things building IEnumerable sublists.  Maybe the C style for loop is actually your best bet :)

Comment: You're right, it is. Please close this! I think my title is better though.

Comment: Also, those LINQs are nasty lol. I'll just stick to the forloop version with slight modifications to remove the exception handling, much more readable.

Comment: If u change your condition thresholdList.Count -1, you can avoid the exception

Comment: `var signalStrengthBuckets = thresholdList.Skip(1).Select((v, i) => new MinMaxRange<int>(thresholdList[i], v)).ToList()`

Comment: Check out `MoreLinq`'s `PairWise` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs